# Is it a bug? Javascript changes numeric value of the variable upon assignment

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

Ok, this will sound crazy, but I've tested it on several browsers and three different machines (all Windows though). As soon as I assign specific numeric value to the variable, it immediately increments. The problem for me is that this specific value is one of the database object ids that shouldn't be changed.

Tried on latest Chrome, Firefox, and Edge. It's really simple to test:

```js
let a = 17841410687956931;
console.log(a);
// output is 17841410687956932
```

I've also tried `let a = [17841410687956931];` and `let a = {17841410687956931: "anything"};`, and it still increments. `const` and `var` don't change a thing. Note that 17841410687956930 and 17841410687956932 are perfectly fine and do not misbehave.

Am I seeing things? Can this be some easter egg? Can you recommend me a good doctor?

Comment: Nah, you've just ran out of precision. `17841410687956931 < Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER === false`. You might want to research how floating point arithmetic works, and try BigInts if you really need that precision.

Comment: @FZs, phew, didn't even think that way, silly me, never encountered this problem before. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript uses precision defined by the [IEEE 754](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_math.html) by default. This format provides 53 bits of precision for integer values. The number you provided, 17841410687956931, requires more than 53 bits.

Use BigInt which was introduced in [ECMAScript 2020](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_2020.asp#mark_bigint):

```
let a = BigInt("17841410687956931");
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Treating variable as a BigInt solved the problem with increment, and it even was properly submitted to server-side processing via ajax calls, so no problems with solution at all. Thank you!

Comment: How exactly are you passing it to server side? As a string?

Comment: @SalmanA, I'm appending it to the FormData(), and then run POST fetch with FormData as body. The troublesome ids were in array, now it's array of bigints, no strings involved.

Answer (score 1):

This is a precision issue related to JavaScript's large number processing. JavaScript uses a 64-bit floating-point representation for numbers, and beyond a certain point, it can no longer accurately represent consecutive integers.

Try converting your number to  BigInt by adding "n" at the end, like this:

```js
let a = 17841410687956931n;
console.log(a);
```

"n" tells JavaScript to treat the number as `BigInt`, which will handle large integers more accurately.

Comment: Just as a complementary comment, the precision with javaScript is only 53 bits however the number occupies 64bits.

Answer (score 0):

Use [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) in order to work with integers of arbitrary Precision without losing accuracy:

```js
let a = BigInt("17841410687956931");
console.log(a.toString());  // output is 17841410687956931
```

So this is not a bug but we can say one of the limitation of JS handling large integer values, since it use IEEE754 standard for double-precision in this case the precision of storing integers is only 53bits.